# Chain asyncio coroutines inline in asyncio.gather

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a hypothetical `asyncio.gather` scenario:

```py
await asyncio.gather(
    cor1,
    [cor2, cor3],
    cor4,
)
```

I'd like `cor2` and `cor3` to be executed in order here. Is there some shortcut way of doing other than defining an outside coroutine like this:

```py
async def cor2_cor3():
    await cor2
    await cor3

await asyncio.gather(
    cor1,
    cor2_cor3,
    cor4,
)
```

Is there a cleaner shortcut for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a cleaner shortcut for this?

asyncio doesn't provide one out of the box. If asyncio tasks had a method equivalent to JavaScript's [`Promise.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), you'd be able to use `asyncio.create_task(cor2()).then(cor3())`. But the asyncio equivalent, [`add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback), is a more low-level construct which just sets up the callback without creating a new future, which makes it inconvenient for chaining.

To execute coroutines in order you will need to write a simple utility function, for example (untested):

```py
async def chain(*aws):
    ret = None
    for aw in aws:
        ret = await aw
    return ret
```

Then you can invoke `gather` as:

```py
await asyncio.gather(cor1(), chain(cor2(), cor3()), cor4())
```

Comment: There's a problem with your proposed chain function as it would return only the last result of chained coroutines. Ideally it should return results of all coroutines and then later they should also be unpacked in `asyncio.gather` manually. Nevertheless this does answer my question and it seems you're described approach is the best one here.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Good point, fortunately it's trivial to collect results into a list and return it. This goes to show that it's not unambiguous what "chain" means - based on `cor2_cor3` example I assumed you either didn't care about the result at all, or you only wanted the result of the last coroutine. Also "chaining" might imply passing the result of one coroutine as the argument to the next one. I suspect that semantic ambiguity was part of reason why chain was omitted from the stdlib, the other part being that it's easy enough to implement when you do need it.